# SELECT statement issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a modal pop up that currently holds checkboxes in it for an admin to be able to add features to a product. I needed to change this to be able to get tied to the category of the product on the current page, but my sql statement isn't working.

The tables here are Feature, Category and Marketing. Feature connects to Category with the CategoryID(named CategoryID in Feature & in Category tables), and Feature connects to Marketing with the FeatureID(called MarketingData in the Marketing table)

The MarketingTypeID of 3 tells the Marketing table to look for a Feature and will jump over to the feature table. The select statement worked before I added the Category table stuff to it, so obviously I coded that part wrong. Can someone help me get the select statement working?

This works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FeatureID, FeatureTitle 
FROM Feature 
WHERE FeatureID NOT IN 
(SELECT m.MarketingData FROM Marketing 
WHERE MarketingTypeID = 3 AND ProductID = @ProductID) 
ORDER BY FeatureTitle
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.FeatureID, f.FeatureTitle FROM Feature f 
INNER JOIN Category c 
ON c.CategoryID = f.CategoryID 
WHERE f.CategoryID = @CategoryID 
AND f.FeatureID NOT IN 
(SELECT m.MarketingData FROM Marketing m 
WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 3 AND m.ProductID = @ProductID) 
ORDER BY f.FeatureTitle
```

[image]

**EX:** FeatureID #23, Web Tutorials, has a CategoryID of 32....this Category is called Platforms and is located in the Category table. FeatureID #23 is NOT in the Marketing table, therefore is NOT associated to the Product that was chosen, which is ProductID #1. I need a checkbox that says Web Tutorials to show up in the modal. Like I said before, it was just fine before I added all the stuff about the Category that is associated to the product that was selected by the user.

**UPDATE:** I have no idea why I was trying to write that statement the way I had it. I realized that it was much easier than I had originally thought and changed the statement. This works now, thank you for all the help everyone! I changed the SELECT statement to:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT f.FeatureID, f.FeatureTitle 
FROM Feature f 
LEFT JOIN Category c ON c.CategoryID = f.CategoryID 
WHERE f.CategoryID IN 
(SELECT CategoryID FROM CategoryLink 
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID) 
AND f.FeatureID NOT IN 
(SELECT m.MarketingData FROM Marketing m WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 3 
AND m.ProductID = @ProductID) 
ORDER BY f.FeatureTitle"
```

Comment: Is the screenshot of your database structure up to date? I see no CategoryID column in the Feature table

Comment: The Feature table does not have a CategoryID field from this Products Database picture.

Comment: oh geez, you're right, I forgot to add that when I updated the documentation the other day! Thanks for pointing that out. "Doesn't work" means that there are no results in the modal pop up. I deliberately deleted a feature from a product to test and it never popped back up into the modal. Features immediately popped back into the modal before I added the Category stuff to the statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compare this `JOIN`:

```
 FROM Feature f INNER JOIN Category c ON c.CategoryID = f.CategoryID
```

with the database structure you'll see that you're trying to use a column (`Feature.CategoryID`) that does not exist in your database.  In fact, with the existing design you're going to have to write a pretty involved query to get from `Feature` to `Category`.

It may be true, however that there is a more direct relationship between Categories and the Features they can have that is not yet represented in your database.  If that's true, you'll need to add a table `CategoryFeatureLink`, then use that table along with `Category` and `Feature` in a three-way `JOIN`.

Comment: No, it was my mistake by not adding that to the document. I just added the CategoryID column to the Feature table yesterday, I apologize for that. I will update and switch pictures.

Comment: I updated the documentation to include the recent changes I made to the database. Actually adding the extra table might've made it easier but I was told to add a new column, not a new table.

Comment: In that case, I suspect that you don't have data in the database that satisfies the now-rather-specific requirements of the query.  Could you post the data from a few rows from each involved table that you think should be returned by the query?

Comment: I have edited my original post to include an example of data in my database to clarify what I am looking for

Comment: Are you sure @CategoryID is 32 when you run this query?

Comment: You were right about the CategoryID, I edited the SELECT statement and my code above.

Answer (score 0):

*This is my second answer to this question, pursuing a different problem with the query.*

Is the MarketingData field NULLable?  If so, and if your sub-query returns and NULL values, your statement may not evaluate as you expect depending on certain database settings.

In theory, this won't make a difference between the two queries because they both contain the same sub-query, but if you happened to test with different @ProductID you may only have come across the problem with a particular product.